# What does sys.path.append("..") do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I bumped into this statement in a Python script: `sys.path.append("..")`
I did some research, but I could not find what it does.

I know `sys.path.append()` function appends a path at the end of the PYTHONPATH list. But what does `".."` stand for?

Needless to say, this Python scripts does not work if I comment the line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: It adds the `..` to the paths that Python searches for imports, so you can import things from `..` (which is the parent of the current directory) .

Comment: Well, that is clear that it looks like it refers to parent directory, and it has been  my first thought. Though, when I change `sys.path.append("..")` to `sys.path.append(absolute-path-to-parent-directory)`, it does not work and throw a `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to load a module from that directory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`".."` is a way of saying/referencing the parent of the current working directory.